# Blazor difference between a lambda callback or a direct callback

Tags: c#, lambda, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

So I was experimenting with Blazor and I'd like to understand the difference between these two.

```cs
<p @onclick="OnClickCallback">Click me normal</p>

<p @onclick="async () => await OnClickCallback()">Click me lambda</p>

@code {

  private async Task OnClickCallback()
  {
    await Task.Delay(500);
  }

}
```

What is the difference between these two approaches. What happens behind the scenes. I've found some issues with EF Core (which is a whole other topic) where the lambda approach did not throw an exception, and the normal did.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 don't understand that either. Thanks for your upvote. I believe a lot of people simply don't know this. So I want to know what my program does, not just know if it works.

Comment: Yeah, I think the metric is, "I can't immediately answer this question, so it's a question that doesn't matter.  Thumb down!"

Comment: @RoyBerris - To elaborate on Johnathan's answer.  The important bit is here: `private async Task OnClickCallback()` returning a Task.  By doing so the Blazor Event handler can wait on `OnClickCallback` completing before calling `StateHasChanged` on the component.  All too many make that error and then manually have to call `StateHasChanged` to get the UI to update with the latest changes.

Comment: @RoyBerris.  I've made some minor editing to your question to try and get it re-opened.  You have to change something to re-submit it.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference between these two approaches

It adds another function, which means it introduces another call on the stack.

Also, because this is an `async` lambda, it allocates another `Task` instance.

This being said, using the former will have a negligible performance benefit.

---

For completeness, there is a third alternative that would prevent another `Task` being used, but would still result in another function call:

```
() => OnClickCallback()
```

Answer (score 1):

In Blazor, that's a very good question.  I don't really know if they compile differently, but I wanted to mention something that's quite important: a lambda method can pass a variable other than the normal event variables that go with the event.  It's very useful to do something like this:

```
@foreach (var item in SomeCustomList)
    {
        <p @onclick="async (e) => await OnClickCallback(e, item )">Click me lambda</p>
    }
```

Comment: It would be preferable to elide the `async..await` keywords in this instance, otherwise each `item` would result in an additional `Task`: `e => OnClickCallback(e, item)`.